# Unexpected token with valid json?

Tags: json, node.js

Why can't I print this simple json? jsonlint.com says this is valid

json:

```
[
   {
      "token_start_offset": "0.00",
      "token_duration": "4.00",
      "token_base_start_offset": "0.00",
      "token_base_duration": "4.00",
      "token_type": "background_noise",
      "token_background_noise_type": "other",
      "session_id": "1459194633575",
      "token_base_form": "…",
      "token_print_form": "…",
      "session_boundary": "begin",
      "nonspeech_boundary": "begin",
      "token_id": "0"
   }
]
```

app.js:

```
var testJson = require('./json');

console.log(testJson);
```

But when I run this, I get the below error:

Error:

```
module.js:428
    throw err;
    ^

SyntaxError: C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\format test\json.json: Unexpected token  
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..json (module.js:425:27)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\format test\app.js:1:78)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
```

Windows 10
node -v 4.2.6

Comment: at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Grant\Desktop\format test\app.js:1:78)
line 1, 78th character

Comment: Try changing your require file name from "./json" to "./json.json"...Node might be trying to load it as a source file, even though it's JSON. And make sure the filename is actually 'json.json". ;)

Comment: @RobRaisch didn't work, and I can confirm that the filename is correct

Comment: Make sure don't have any other "hidden" chars are in the file. I have tried it with win 10 node v5.3.0 and it is working...

Comment: @It-Z yeah, that must be it. I copied and pasted the json as it appears on this page and replaced my file with it and it works. If there was some way to sanitize json of hidden characters, that would answer the question for future reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the JSON parser in Node's `require()` assumes ASCII characters and your example contains a Unicode character: `…`. If you replace all instances of `…` with `\u2026`, your JSON should parse.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that those ellipsises were one character. I replaced it, but it still doesn't work, sadly

Comment: What operating system and version of Node are you using? (node -v will report its version)

Comment: And your operating system?

Comment: See my last comment on your question.